# Spool a RTF file directly to a Lipi printer from a JAVA class

Tags: java, printing, rtf

I have **RTF** file on the sever I want directly take the printout of the file using a JAVA Program.
I tried the following code (Consider only one printer(**LIPI**) is connected to server)

```
        FileInputStream psStream = null;
        try {
            psStream = new FileInputStream("C://SampleBoard2.rtf");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
              ffne.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (psStream == null) {
                return;
            }  
        DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset);

        
        PrintService myPrinter = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++){
            
            String svcName = services[i].toString();
            myPrinter = services[i];
        }
      if (myPrinter != null) {
          DocPrintJob job = myPrinter.createPrintJob();
          try {
          job.print(myDoc, aset);

          } catch (Exception pe) {pe.printStackTrace();}
      } else {
        System.out.println("no printer services found");
      }
```

The file gets spooled to the printer and print also starts, but the printer prints the contents of thge RTF file like a **text** file contents. What should be done to render the file to **RTF** and then print?

I get something like this in the print.

> \rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0 Times New
> Roman;}{\f1\froman\fcharset0 Courier;}{\f2\froman\fcharset0
> Arial;}{\f3\froman\fcharset0
> unknown;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}{\stylesheet
> {\style\s0 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs24\cf0 Normal;}{\style\s3
> \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs26\b\cf0 heading 3;}{\style\s2
> \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs28\b\i\cf0 heading 2;}{\style\s1
> \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs32\b\cf0 heading 1;}} ..... .... ...
>
> .... ... ...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need an RTF rendering engine in the same way that you need to render HTML pages before printing.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Can you suggest a `RTF rendering engine` for `JAVA` and where can I get one and how to place it between the printer and the class...

Comment: No.  I do not have experience with RTF engines.  Be prepared to pay money though.

Comment: ohhh...thats not very encouraging...

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, nasty business. The easiest way would be to invoke an external program like wordpad or openoffice to directly print the file - f.e. if you invoke `write.exe /p filename.rtf` it will pop up the printing dialogue. OpenOffice is supposed to have a bridge with Java, and you might want to look into `javax.activation`.

Comment: Another question mentioned that OpenOffice had some shortcomings in rendering Office RTF's (some graphics stuff).  Better be certain to stay within the limitations of the rendering engine.